How are customly shaped drawing selection features made?
I'm not a beginner programmer, but i can't think of a way to implement a custom selection feature in a way that is not overly complicated and/or slow in execution.
What i'm referring to is the function of the tool that is a basic feature in drawing programs (even in Microsoft Paint from back in 1995) where you can draw a custom shape, and only the pixels inside of the area you outlined will be selected.
The selecting part is not what i'm interested in, but the general method of applying something to only the pixels/cells/any kind of units inside a customly defined perimeter in a data structure.

Question's a bit vague.  "the general method of applying something to only the pixels/cells/any kind of units inside a customly defined perimeter in a data structure" - one easy, clean way is to create a mask layer from the selection (after floodfilling inside the outline), transform the entire image is some way but only take the changes that overlap the mask.  This assumes you're dealing in pixels rather than vectors, but you mention pixels and Paint, so that seems the case.  No advanced data structures needed for masking - it's just a 2d pixel situation, likely offered by your graphics lib.

I don't need it in graphics, it was just an example of it's use. I need to know the process of how it's achieved to only apply a certain action to units inside an outlined area. Let's say there is a data grid, there are customly selected connected cells in it, which form the outline inside of which i want to affect the cells. I assumed the process behind custom graphic selection works similarly and could give a clue. It's vague because i don't need a specific implementation of it but the concept behind it.

The question is a lot vague. "the general method of applying ... inside a customly defined perimeter" touches on a lot of computer graphics topics including polygon representation and rendering. It's rather difficult to summarize that in a short answer here. I'd suggest a good introduction to computer graphics and some study.

It's not necessary for it to be related to graphics at all, i'm interested in how a similar functionality could be achieved in any way. I'm also not new to computer graphics, and the only way i can think of to achieve a similar result is to have the perimeter's points be used as vertices of a primitive which's texture is taken from the canvas, and then subtract this primitive from the original canvas, But then the texture coordinates of each vertex would have to be calculated so it doesn't get distorted, which would use a lot of resources.
